# The set of all functions mapping set $A$ to set $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $F$ as defined here the set of all functions from set $A$ to set $B$?

$F=\{f\in 2^{A\times B}:\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow\exists y (y\in B\wedge (x,y)\in f))\wedge \forall x,y_1,y_2 ((x,y_1)\in f\wedge (x,y_2)\in f\rightarrow y_1=y_2)\}$

If $A$ was non-empty, then $B$ would also have to be non-empty, but my construction in no way depended on either set being non-empty. How can this be? Have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you’re using the notation $2^S$ for the power set of $S$, then yes, you’ve correctly described the set of functions from $A$ to $B$. If $A\ne\varnothing$ and $B=\varnothing$, $A\times B=\varnothing$, so the only $f\in 2^{A\times B}$ is $\varnothing$, and it fails to satisfy the first clause of the definition and is therefore not actually in $F$. Thus, $F=\varnothing$ in this case, just as it should.